# HTML page working in Chrome and safari and not working in Internet explore

Tags: javascript

I have written a java script which is working in chrome and safari but not on internet explorer .I dont see an error when i click on the format button . can i know how should i de-bug this

this is the code

```js
function refineNumber() {
  var arrayWithCharacters = document.getElementById('phonenumber').value.split("");
  var blankArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayWithCharacters.length; i++) {
    var hireWyattInIT = Number(arrayWithCharacters[i]);
    if (isNaN(hireWyattInIT) != true) {
      blankArray += arrayWithCharacters[i].trim();
    }
  }
  if (blankArray.length === 11 && ['0', '1'].includes(blankArray.charAt(0))) {
    blankArray = blankArray.substr(1, 10);
  }
  if (blankArray.length > 10) {
    document.getElementById('validation').innerHTML = 'The phone number you have entered has more than 10 digits.Please check';
    document.getElementById('submitData').style.display = 'none';
  } else if (blankArray.length < 10) {
    document.getElementById('validation').innerHTML = 'The phone number you have entered has less than 10 digits.Please check';
    document.getElementById('submitData').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('validation').innerHTML = 'The Phone number you have entered has been formatted.Please verify before you submit';
    document.getElementById('submitData').style.display = 'block';
  }
  document.getElementById('validation').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('phonenumber').value = blankArray;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Phone Number (10-digits): &nbsp;
  <input type="text" id="phonenumber" name="btn">&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <input type="button" name="Query" onclick="refineNumber()" value="Format" class="btn">
  <br><br>
  <h4 id="validation" style="display: none;"></h4>
</div>
```

Can you help me fix this?

Comment: what is not working in IE?

Comment: Please post what is the error in internet explorer developer console

Comment: The refineNumber function

Comment: Actually , we have a format button which when clicked should format the number . It is not working . There is no error

Comment: `document.getElementById('submitData')` is null. Your HTML doesn't have an element with that `id`.

Comment: Asking a question and never responding to answers given must be considered rude behaviour by any standards.

Comment: Hi @connexo,sorry for the late response . This

Answer (score 0):

[No version of Internet Explorer supports `Array.prototype.includes`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=array-includes).

So replace

```
['0', '1'].includes(blankArray.charAt(0))
```

with

```
blankArray.charAt(0) === '0' || blankArray.charAt(0) === '1'
```

or

```
['0', '1'].indexOf(blankArray.charAt(0)) > -1
```

Answer (score -1):

sorry for the late response and Thank you for the help .

I have used the code you have given and it didnt work.

Later i found out that the trim function too didnt work .

After few trials this is what i figured out and it worked

I tried the below code and it worked 
`

```
var numberregex=document.getElementById('phonenumber').value.replace(/^\+?[0,1]|\D/g, '');


              if (numberregex.length > 10) {

                        document.getElementById('validation').innerHTML ='The phone number you have entered has more than 10 digits.Please check';

                        document.getElementById('submitData').style.display = 'none';

                } else if (numberregex.length < 10) {

                        document.getElementById('validation').innerHTML ='The phone number you have entered has less than 10 digits.Please check';

                        document.getElementById('submitData').style.display = 'none';

                } else {

                        document.getElementById('validation').innerHTML ='The Phone number you have entered has been formatted.Please verify before you submit';

                        document.getElementById('submitData').style.display = 'block';

}
document.getElementById('validation').style.display = 'block';
                        document.getElementById('phonenumber').value = numberregex;
```

Comment: The code you showcased does not make use of `trim`. We cannot fix problems you don't even show.